# Update a Column in Table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a requirement in which there is a table like below

```
Invoice Date        Year    Amount
1001    04-NOV-15   2015    100
1001    04-NOV-16   2016    400
1001    04-NOV-17   2017    600
1002    01-OCT-17   2014    1000
```

I am expecting a column at the end that should calculate the difference in the fashion

```
Invoice Date        Year    Amount    Calculation
1001    04-NOV-15   2015    100       0
1001    04-NOV-16   2016    400       ((04-NOV-16)-(04-NOV-15))/(400-300)
1001    04-NOV-17   2017    600       ((04-NOV-17)-(04-NOV-16))/(600-400)
1002    01-OCT-14   2014    1000      0
1002    01-OCT-18   2018    2000      ((01-OCT-18)-(01-OCT-14))/(2000-1000)
1003    01-JAN-14   2014    1000      0
```

The calculation column is what is required and

i tried the below query which gave the amount difference

```
select invoice, 
       date_value,
       Year_va,
       amount,
       amount-lag(amount) over (partition by invoice

                                                order by date_value,invoice
                                               ) diff                                      
 from sample;
```

when tried the

```
select invoice, 
       date_value,
       Year_va,
       amount,
       MOD(date_value-lag(date_value),amount-lag(amount)) over (partition by invoice

                                                order by date_value,invoice
                                               ) diff                                      
 from sample;
```

it failed with the window function error.

Can anyone help in this please....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `mod()` if you want the *difference*?

```
( (date_value - lag(date_value) over (partition by invoice order by date_value) ) /
  (amount - lag(amount) over (partition by invoice order by date_value) )
) as ratio
```

You might want a `coalesce()` to get `0`s instead of `NULL`s (your query doesn't handle this, but your sample data suggests you might want to do so).

Comment: i have not used the coalesce(). can you help me with the whole query. I am using oracle sql developer

Comment: Can you please look into this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208379/multiple-rows-values-into-a-single-row?noredirect=1#comment81365856_47208379

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Gordon, you can use `lag` function along with `coalesce` as below to get your desired result.

```
SELECT t1.*
    ,coalesce((
            date_value - lag(date_value) OVER (
                PARTITION BY invoice ORDER BY date_value
                )
            ) / (
            amount - lag(amount) OVER (
                PARTITION BY invoice ORDER BY date_value
                )
            ), 0) AS ratio
FROM table1 t1;
```

You can also use `ANSI` equivalent i.e. `min/max` along with `ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` as below.

```
SELECT t1.*
    ,coalesce((
            date_value - min(date_value) OVER (
                PARTITION BY invoice ORDER BY date_value ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING
                        AND 1 PRECEDING
                )
            ) / (
            amount - min(amount) OVER (
                PARTITION BY invoice ORDER BY date_value ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING
                        AND 1 PRECEDING
                )
            ), 0) AS ratio
FROM table1 t1;
```

**Result:**

```
INVOICE      DATE_VALUE             YEAR    AMOUNT  RATIO
-----------------------------------------------------------
1001         04.11.2015 00:00:00    2015    100     0
1001         04.11.2016 00:00:00    2016    400     1.22
1001         04.11.2017 00:00:00    2017    600     1.8250
1002         01.10.2017 00:00:00    2014    1000    0
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/ZZNR36277)**

Comment: Can you please help me with the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208379/multiple-rows-values-into-a-single-row/47208605#47208605